# How to disable onitem click in list view particular row in android

Tags: android

How to disable list view on item click in particular row in android.if value is search i have to disable the onitem click event of particular row in list view in android can anybody tell how to do?

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long arg3) 
{
if(your condition)
    {
    //your click event code
    }
    else
    {
    //nothing
    }
}
});
```

Comment: droid I want to disable the listview item click of particular row

Comment: then put this condition in your list item click event @user386430 check update

Comment: +1 @ user386430 CapDroid is right, just put this in onListItemClick

Comment: What about the situation when item views itself contain one or more clickable views?

Answer (score 1):

you for comple row

```
onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {


       if(Clickable condition ){
              super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
               // your code .........
          }else{


          }
    }
```